# How is method reference operator accepted where Runnable Instance is expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, method-reference

I recently came across below sample code where method reference operator is used to reference a method call. There are 2 questions for which i am looking for an answer
1. The execute method where its called expects Runnable class. This code compiles file and gives no error why (App class is not Runnable)?
2. if I replace executorService.execute(app::someMethod); with executorService.execute(app.someMethod()); it give an compile error why?

```
public class Temp {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Temp.class);

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments - not used
 */`enter code here`
public static void main(String... args) {
    final App app = new App();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        executorService.execute(app::someMethod);
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: Waiting on executor service shutdown!");
    }
}

}
class App {
     public void someMethod() {
           // Some logic
     }
}
```

Comment: `app::someMethod` and `app.someMethod()` exhibit different behavior, because they are entirely different constructs. Perhaps, you should start with [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) first.

Comment: You could use a statement lambda, `()->app.someMethod()` which is nearly equivalent to the method reference.

Answer (score 7):

`ExecutorService.execute` expects an argument of type `Runnable`.

To answer your last question first... `App.someMethod()` is a `void` method (i.e. it doesn't return anything). As `app.someMethod()`'s return type is `void`, and as the `void` type cannot be assigned to a variable or method argument of type `Runnable`, you are getting a compilation error.

Now, as to your first question... The `Runnable` interface is a *functional interface* because it declares a single abstract method (SAM):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {

    void run();
}
```

The SAM here is `void run()`, which doesn't receive any arguments and is a `void` method.

Now, the method reference `app::someMethod` is *targeting* the `void someMethod()` method of the `App` class, whose signature **matches** that one of the `run` method of the `Runnable` interface (by *match* I mean that both methods' return type is `void` and that neither one of them receives any argument).

So, when you pass the `app::someMethod` method reference as an argument to the `executorService.execute` method, the compiler safely *transforms* it to a `Runnable` instance.

---

**EDIT:** As user @MC Emperor highlights in the comments, the `someMethod` method of the `App` class *may* return something (i.e. it doesn't have to be necessarily a `void` method). In this case, as stated by the spec (see [JLS § 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3), thanks for the link!), the return value would be simply discarded.

This is because in Java, values returned by methods can be discarded, and method references (and also lambda expressions) honor this behavior.

Comment: Thank For the explanation. i get it now.

Comment: Note that `app::someMethod` *may* return something. If it does, it is simply discarded, see [JLS § 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3).

Comment: @MC Emperor. That is a very valuable comment! It is important to point out that in this case, return type is discarded, and that prevents us from getting an error as in case of app.someMethod().

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, App class is not Runnable, but in your example it is not the App object that you are passing to execute method, but instead you do method reference there.

2) app::someMethod is a reference to an instance method of a particular object. app.someMethod() is just a call to someMethod() and it is expected that it returns an object implementing Runnable interface. It is not, that's why you get an error.

Comment: I understood. Thank for the explanation.